# What is the best way to add or remove a class for progressive enhancement?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, progressive-enhancement

I am working on a site that uses minimal JS, mostly for toggling menus on mobile, that sort of thing.

I would like the site to still be navigable if js is disabled. I've come up with 2 solutions that work, but I would like to know if one is better than the other or if there is something altogether different I should be doing.

Which is better?

Example A

```html
<body>
 <noscript>
  <div class="no-js">
 </noscript>
 ... stuff here ...
 <noscript>
    </div>
</noscript>
```

or

Example B

```html
<body id="body" class="body no-js">
 ... stuff here ...
<script>document.getElementById("body").classList.remove("no-js");</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example A is invalid HTML.

HTML must be arranged in a strict hierarchy.

An element (e.g. your `<div>`) cannot start as a child of an element (e.g. your `<noscript>`) without also having the matching end tag inside the same `<noscript>`).

With option A eliminated, only option B remains.

Comment: ...and option B can be rather simpler: `document.body.classList.remove("no-js");` or `document.body.className = "";` (to support obsolete browsers without `classList`), in both cases removing `id="body"` from `<body>`.